# Scroll page to a div on scroll jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

My conecpt is that on triggering scroll, even if it goes 1px top the page should automatically scroll to a particular div. and then nav bar appears. Before that the page will be plain with logo at the center. But some issues are there. Kindly help.

Below is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
    if (sc > 1) {
        $("#header-sroll").removeClass("scroll-display");
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
        }, 800);
    } else {
        $("#header-sroll").addClass("scroll-display");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use smooth scroll concept, scrolling only between multiple parts

```
http://jsfiddle.net/NGj7F/
```

also this might help you

```
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js
```

Comment: Almost like this. But from 2nd div it should scroll normally.

Comment: don't add class to that second div for scroll